# Bootstrap img-responsive class not working correctly

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently having a problem where the bootstrap `img-responsive` class isn't working as it should due to me needing the image to be as far right in the div box as possible. I have two identically sized arrows which surrounds titles of my site. When the browser is scaled down to mobile size, the left arrow appears smaller and more distorted than the right counterpart.

**Full Sized Title**
[image: Full sized title]

**Phone Sized Title**

[image: Phone Sized Title]

HTML:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3"> </div> 
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 arrow-right">
                <img class="img-responsive img-right" src="img/arrow-right.png" alt="">
            </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-2 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">RSVP</h2>
                </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 arrow-left">
                <img class="img-responsive img-left" src="img/arrow-left.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3"> </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow-right {
   padding-top: 12px;
}

.arrow-left {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 0;
 }
@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .img-right {
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      margin-left: 34px;

  }
  .img-left {
      margin: auto;
      margin-right: 30px;
  }

}
```

My question would be, is there an easier way to get these arrows as close to the titles as possible and have them scale down to phone sized perfectly?

Comment: can you please make snippet or fiddle of it?

Comment: @sagarkodte Hi. Is there a way to include the bootstrap package into jsfiddle? I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: just click on external resource on left side

Comment: @sagarkodte http://www.bootply.com/J0wuzzATeW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the XS and make 4/4/4

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3"> </div> 
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2 arrow-right">
                <img class="img-responsive img-right" src="img/arrow-right.png" alt="">
            </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">RSVP</h2>
                </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2 arrow-left">
                <img class="img-responsive img-left" src="img/arrow-left.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3"> </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It worked! That's great, thanks! Would you be able to explain why this happened? I'm kinda curious. Was the `col-xs-3` too small for the images?

Comment: it is because of col-xs-6 this place will be big and you dont have much thing inside so will generate a lot of white space

Comment: better to check this part: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed

Answer (score 1):

I think the blurry image is due to `display: block`, for getting the image as close to the text as possible you could consider using `::after` or `::before` pseudo-elements. Also you could try the following HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 arrow-right">    
        </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 text-center">
                <img class="img-responsive img-right" src="img/arrow-right.png" alt="">
                <h2 class="section-heading">RSVP</h2>
                <img class="img-responsive img-left" src="img/arrow-left.png" alt=""> 
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Also, could you post a fiddle or http://www.bootply.com/?

EDIT -- (after bootply response)

using a little CSS i got it working (without the use of media queries etc.). The CSS is now a lot less and I hope this is what you are looking for (because the images are as close as possible to the text). Using `float: left` to the `img, h2` and a little `padding-top: 24px` for the images got it lined up. See bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/2Hp6stSs9B

Comment: This is the bootply link http://www.bootply.com/J0wuzzATeW thanks for your answer, although it didn't seem to work.